# Spark Jobserver too slow respect Apache Spark Queries

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-jobserver

Using Jobserver Spark-2.0-preview and Apache Spark 2.1.1

The execution time per query is not greater than 1s when I check on the spark UI, but I receive the response from jobserver after 10 seconds and much more.
[image: Spark Completed Queries]
I'm querying parquet files and I'm using java.

This is and example of my code, basically I create the sparksession using the SparkContext provided by the jobserver.

```
public class SOverflow extends VIQ_SparkJob {

private static final String CUBE_USERS_V_DE = "spark_cube_users_v_de";
private static final String CUBE_USERS_V_EN = "spark_cube_users_v_en";

@Override
public Object runJob(SparkContext jsc, Config jobConfig) {
    Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String query = jobConfig.getString("query");
    try {
        sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .sparkContext(jsc)
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///value_iq/spark-warehouse/")
                .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
                .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer", "8m")
                .getOrCreate();
        Class<?>[] classes = new Class<?>[1];
        classes[0] = SOverflow.class;
        sparkSession.sparkContext().conf().registerKryoClasses(classes);

        getDataFrameFromParket("spark_cube_users_v" + "/tenant_id=" + getTENANT_ID()).createOrReplaceTempView("spark_cube_users_v");

        getDataFrameFromMySQL("value_iq", "lookup_values").filter(new Column("lookup_domain").equalTo("customer_type")).createOrReplaceTempView("lookup_values");

        sparkSession.sql(jdbcMySQL.getViewQuery(CUBE_USERS_V_DE)).createOrReplaceTempView("cube_users_v_de");
        sparkSession.sql(jdbcMySQL.getViewQuery(CUBE_USERS_V_EN)).createOrReplaceTempView("cube_users_v_en");

        List<String> list = sparkSession.sql(query).toJSON().takeAsList(10000);
        String result = "[";
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            result += (i == 0 ? "" : ",") + list.get(i);
        }
        result += "]";
        log(MyLog.INFORMATION, "runJob()", "Tooks " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + "s to execute query: " + query + ".");
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}
}
```

My question is: Why do I get those long time response when in the spark UI the queries are really fast?

Comment: Are you creating adhoc context per job?

Comment: @noorul,no, I use a single context for all jobs.

Comment: But you are creating sparkSession and from that  context per job.

Comment: @noorul, yes, I'm creating it using the context that the job server pass as parameter to the runJob method. Did you see another way? Or I have to prescind from SparkSession object?

Comment: I think you should not do that as you already have sparkContext in sjc parameter.

Comment: @noorul, then which way shall I use to invoque the SQLContext? could be `SQLContext sqlc = new SQLContext(sparkContext);` which btw is deprecated on Apache Spark 2.1? Will be faster than creating the SparkSession object? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure SparkSession is supported yet by SJS. Did you look at https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/doc/contexts.md ?

Comment: @noorul, thanks for pointing this out. I'm doing some tests whit that but when I try to call a job on a sql-context then I get `viq_spark.job.CubePurchaseDetails cannot be cast to spark.jobserver.api.SparkJobBase` . My class `CubePurchaseDetails implements JSqlJob<String>`